# No-op subscriber to events in C# - null checking redundant

Tags: c#

So if I do something like this on my event declaration:

```
public event MyDelegate MyEvent = delegate { };
```

I read that this makes null checks redundant, that there will be a no-op subscriber.

I'm curious how this works under the hood. What exactly happens and is this a good practice, or should I stick with usual null check before firing the event handler?

Comment: Since C# 6.0 you can do: `MyEvent?.Invoke`

Comment: "I read that..." - providing a link to where you read it may help those answering your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The null checks aren't tricky because of an extra `if` - they are tricky because they're unreliable in a multi-threaded environment.

It's a trade-off. If you expect that the event will only have 0-1 delegates, using a (safe) null-check is probably better. If you expect to have multiple subscribers that keep subscribing and unsubscribing, you're better off with the "null-delegate". It does mean an extra delegate in the call chain, but that's usually cheap enough for most uses of events in .NET.

You wouldn't want to use it on e.g. a control that has 50 different events most of which never have a subscriber, or your behaviour changes based on whether there is a subscriber or not.

As for what happens under the hood, well... nothing. This does no magic whatsoever. The trick is in how `+=` works on events / delegates.

If you have a `null` event, and use `+=`, it simply assigns a new delegate to the event. If there already is a delegate, it will create a new delegate, which is a combination of the previous delegate and the new one. If you use that null-delegate, it simply means that there is always some delegate to combine. The usual code for invoking an event can look something like this:

```
var ev = Click;

if (ev != null) ev();
```

This means that if there is no subscriber to the event, there is no invocation. In the null-delegate case, the code is further simplified to

```
Click();
```

This *always* means a delegate invocation - at the very least, your null-delegate is invoked. Sure, it doesn't actually do anything, but you keep the delegate invocation overhead. Again, this is rarely a problem, but there are cases where this is unacceptable.